# Angular load controller dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm new in angularjs, I'm working in one app using laravel, angularjs and requirejs.
my question is: how I can load the controller dynamically when a user request a page (view).
example: if a user request this URL(http://domain.com/#!/page_requested) then I want to load the file page_requested.controller.js and page_request.template.html.
My app structure is:

```
public/
     app/
        main.js
        app.js
        config.js
        todo/
            controllers/
                       page_requested.controller.js
            views/
                 page_requested.template.html
            dirictives/
        ...
```

main.js

```
'use struct';
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/../libPath/',

  paths: {
    jquery      : '/../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery',
    angular     : '/../bower_components/angular/angular',
    ngAnimate   : '/../bower_components/angulat-animate/angular-animate',
    ngAria      : '/../bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria',
    ngMessages  : '/../bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages',
    ngRoute     : '/../bower_components/angular-route/angular-route',
    ngSanitize  : '/../bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize',
        autoLoad        : '/../bower_components/auto-load/lib/index',
    app         : 'app'


  },
  shim: {
    jquery: {
            exports: '$'
        },

        angular: {
            exports: 'angular',
        },
        ngRoute: {
            exports: 'ngRoute',
            deps: ['angular']
        }
  }
});

require(
    [
        'angular', 
        'ngRoute',
        'app',
        'config'
    ], 
    function (angular) {
        var AppRoot = angular.element(document.getElementById('ng-app'));
        AppRoot.attr('ng-controller','app');
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
    }
);
```

app.js

```
'use strict';
define(['angular', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'], function (angular, ngRoute, ngSanitize) {

    angular.module('HashBangURLs', ['ngRoute']).config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
        $locatio
</pre>n.hashPrefix('!');
    }]);

    angular.module('HTML5ModeURLs', ['ngRoute']).config(['$locationProvider', function($location) {
        $location.html5Mode(true);
    }]);


    var app = angular.module('app', ['HashBangURLs', 'ngSanitize'], function (
                                                            $routeProvider, 
                                                             $locationProvider, 
                                                             $httpProvider) {

    });

});
```

config.js

```
'use strict';

define(['angular', 'app'], function (angular, app) {

    return app.config([ '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

$routeProvider  
    .when('/:name',{
        templateUrl: function(v){return "app/todo/views/"+v.name+".template.html";},
        controller: function($q, $route, $rootScope){
                    return $route.current.params.name + "Controller";
                }
    })
    .otherwise("/");
}]);
});
```

My controller page_requestedController

```
define(['angular', 'app', function(angular, app){
  app.controller('page_rquestedController', function($scope){
    $scope.title = "Hi from page_requested.controller.js";
    console.log('controller is exicuted...');
  });
}]);
```

Now my question is:

1. It is correct what I'm looking for? "is this secure for my app?
2. I will like to not use layzyLoad.js- it great script, but it's not what I want to use on this app.
3. If I have to register my controller and add the script element to my body, how can I do this from my config.js? is the angular.dirictives can do this?

Comment: You are loading the controllers dynamically already, through $routeProvider in your config.js

Comment: Hi @Salil, but dosen't appear anything in view (html), do you know what can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
'use strict';
define([],function() {
  var app = angular.module('UConnect',['ngRoute','ngAnimate','ui.materialize','yaru22.angular-timeago']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$controllerProvider', '$provide',function($routeProvider, $controllerProvider, $provide) {
      // Register your component
      app.register = {
          controller: $controllerProvider.register,
          factory: $provide.factory,
          service: $provide.service
      };
      // Add resolver for load controller through require.js
      function resolveController(dependencies) {
          return {
            load: ['$q', '$rootScope', function ($q, $rootScope) {
              var defer = $q.defer();
              require(dependencies, function () {
                  defer.resolve();
                  $rootScope.$apply();
              });
              return defer.promise;
            }]
          }
      };
    $routeProvider
    .when("/Pages", {
        templateUrl : "templates/Pages.html",
        controller: 'PagesCtrl', // Add controller name.
        resolve: resolveController(['controller/PagesCtrl']) // Call resolver to load controller.
    })
    .when("/ContactUs", {
        templateUrl : "templates/ContactUs.html",
        controller: 'ContactUsCtrl',
        resolve: resolveController(['controller/ContactUsCtrl'])
    })
    ;
    $routeProvider.otherwise('/Pages');
  }]);
  angular.element(document).ready(function () {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['Uconnect']);
  });
  return app;
});
```

You just need to add multiple $routeProvider to register your view & controller. require.js will load controller when state is changed.